# # of columns in two selected tables or a query of a union query do not match

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a simple qry that give me  error

```
SELECT * 

FROM qry_ExecSum

inner join qry_IDS_IT_Everything on qry_ExecSum.P_Code = qry_IDS_IT_Everything.P_Code
```

It works good If change the * to column names like this :

```
SELECT qry_ExecSum.P_Code

FROM qry_ExecSum

inner join qry_IDS_IT_Everything on qry_ExecSum.P_Code = qry_IDS_IT_Everything.P_Code
```

All individual queries run good!!

Comment: no it certainly shouldn't be the case

Comment: Put simply, columns exist in both tables with the same name.  the output of a query can not have columns with the same name.

Answer (score 3):

Hope you are receiving error `The multi-part identifier could not be bound`, since both tables have the column named `P_Code`.

To avoid this you can specify the table name or table alias infront of the column name in the `SELECT`. That is the reason the second query doesn't return the error.

Comment: Microsoft's [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821148.aspx) for joining in Access actually explicitly mentions this situation.